# obtener resultado de promesa

Tags: javascript

quiero obtener el resultado de la promesa pero no puedo, es posible?

```js
function initPromise() {
  return new Promise(function(res,rej) {
    res("uno");
  })
}

let data=initPromise().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); 
    return "dos";
})
console.log(data);//quiero obtener la cadena "dos"
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu ejemplo no es muy bueno porque la promesa retorna "uno" en duro. Y tú quieres obtener "dos".

Supongamos que le puedes pasar un parámetro a `initPromise`

```
function initPromise(numero) {
  return new Promise(function(res,rej) {
    res(numero);
  })
}

let data=initPromise("dos").then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); // imprime "dos";
    return result;
});
```

Como data es una promesa, si la logueas no va a imprimir el valor con que la promesa se resuelve. Te va a imprimir `Promise {<pending>}` (aunque en este caso imprime un objeto vacío... probablemente cosas de los snippets de SO).

Si lo que quieres es obtener el valor de la respuesta en forma síncrona (fuera del then). Esto no se puede hacer más que usando async/await:

```
async function initPromise(numero) {
  return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    res(numero);
  })
}

async function obtenerValor() {
  let data = await initPromise("dos");

  console.log(data);
}

obtenerValor();
```

El problema es que para usar `await` tienes que estar dentro de una función `async` que en el ejemplo es `obtenerValor`.

Tendrás que usar un transpilador (e.g. Babel) para que eso funcione en un browser.

**Addendum:**

Ya que `initPromise` declarado como `async` siempre devuelve una promesa, no tiene sentido retornar una promesa `new Promise()` desde éste. De la misma manera, si el valor retornado es de por sí una promesa, no tiene sentido declarar la función como async. En otras palabras:

```
// devuelve una promesa
function retornaPromesa() {
   return new Promise(...);
}

// también devuelve una promesa
async function retornaValor() {
   return 1;
}

// esto es redundante
async function retornaValorDePromesa() {
   return new Promise(...);
}
```

Ahora, en qué caso tendría sentido el ejemplo redundante?

La gracia de declarar la función como async es que dentro de ella podemos usar `await`. Por ejemplo, para pedir los permisos de un usuario a un API:

```
// queremos hacer algo con permisos antes de retornarlos
async function revisaPermisos() {
   try {
     let permisos = await axios.get('/permisos/123');
     if(!permisos.usuario) {
       throw new Error('No es usuario');
     } else if (!permisos.activo) {
       throw new Error('Es usuario pero no está activo');
     }
     return permisos;
   } catch (err) {
     throw err;
   }
}
```

En este ejemplo, quiero manejar la respuesta en la función en vez de pasarle ese trabajo a quien la llama (dado que la pueden llamar de muchas partes). Si la petición al API tira un error, y `revisaPermisos` es llamado usando `revisaPermisos().then(...).catch(...)` el error aparecerá en el bloque `catch`. Pero **si la llamada al API no tira error**... y sin embargo la respuesta debe cumplir con ciertas condiciones, yo puedo parsear esa respuesta y someterla a ciertas validaciones, arrojando errores customizados por mí cuando no se cumplan.

Puede que esto no venga al caso dada la pregunta del OP, pero es un ejemplo de cuándo tendría sentido declarar como async una función que por dentro llamará a otra función que retorna una promesa.

Comment: `async function initPromise() { return new Promise() })`, es redundante.

Comment: asumo que el OP posteó el método como un mock del método real. `initPromise` debe ser el llamado a algún API. Por eso también se explica que el ejemplo que usó retorne una respuesta en duro.

Comment: Me explico. Una función declarada como `async` siempre va a devolver una promesa. Es redundante declararla como async si ya devuelves manualmente una promesa. Simplificando podrías hacer. `async function initPromise(numero){ return numero; }`.

Comment: Te entiendo completamente, sólo estoy diciendo que el OP en realidad no tiene `return new Promise()` debe tener `return axios.get(...)` o algo así

Comment: Seguiría siendo entonces redundante declararla como async en la declaración de la función initPromise. Únicamente lo he puesto para que los usuarios que vean tu respuesta no se confundan con el uso de async. Saludos!

Comment: Voy a añadir un addendum a mi respuesta para aclarar este aspecto

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría reformules tu código de la siguiente manera

```js
var opera = new Promise(function(res, rej){
  var numero = "uno"
  res(numero)
})


let data = function(){
  opera.then(function(val){
    console.log(val)
  })
console.log("dos")
}

data()
```

Te explico:

1. Asignamos la promesa a una variable, de modo tal que podamos acceder a ella posteriormente, por el nombre de dicha variable
2. El mensaje de "dos" lo asigne a una variable que únicamente va a ser devuelto cuando la promesa se resuelva de manera correcta
3. para acceder a la funcionalidad de la promesa, declaro una variable llamada `data` que ejecutará una función anónima y esta a su vez me permitirá acceder a la promesa y a sus estados
4. Como la promesa esta esperando recibir un valor, paso en el primer then de la `promise` una variable llamada val la cual va a a tomar el valor de "dos", que esta declarado en la variable numero, la `promise` se va a ejecutar primero entonces el mensaje "dos aparece primero"; posteriormente solo mando a imprimir en un `console.log()` el mensaje "uno"
5. Para activar la funcionalidad del código, invoco la función al final de mi código de esta manera `data()`

> Si colocas el `console.log()` fuera del alcance del `then()` se va a
>   imprimir primero el mensaje que dice `dos` pues este mismo no debe
>   esperar a que la promesa se resuelva y por esta misma razón se va a
>   imprimir el mensaje `uno` justo después

Comment: pero quiero el "dos" fuera del then, no es debido?

Comment: solo pon el console.log() fuera del espacio de trabajo del then y sigue funcionando @hubman

Comment: actualice mi pregunta, por malos entendidos del console

Comment: hubiera sido mejor colocar la duda original desde el principio, pues tu nueva pregunta no se parece a la que tenías originalmente

Comment: es que quiera obtener los 3 resultados como mi primer ejemplo

Comment: siguiendo con mi primer pregunta, tu respuesta es que no se puede?

Comment: te saludo @hubman no habia visto que respondiste disculpa, si se puede si miras modifique la respuesta a lo que me comentabas

Comment: es que estas confundiendo un console con un valor, eso no es lo mismo

Comment: ya se que se puede ejecutar consoles y demas dentro de una promesa, pero yo quiero obtener el resultado fuera del .then